# SQL Server Management Studio 2017 change font in grid result

Tags: ssms-2017

I am trying to change font size in grid result in SQL Server Management Studio 2017. But I dont see how to do this. There is not option in Tools->Option->Fonts->and Colour :(

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSMS update + reboot solve problem

Comment: Tried this but mine says my version is up to date. Any other way to solve this?

Comment: I even did a full SSMS uninstall, reinstall, shut off computer completely, and restart. This did not resolve the symptom.